# Are these database indexes correct for my search

Tags: sql-server, index

I am new to `Database Administration`. I am following information provided by: http://www.brentozar.com/blitzindex/

I have a table `VehicleMonitoringLog`. When I execute the `sp_BlitzIndex` script it shows that this is a `Heap`, because it doesn't have a `clustered index`.

[image]

Now, all of our searches on this table are done based on `iAssetId` and `dtUTCDateTime`. This is the Query:

```
Select top (1) * 
from VehicleMonitoringLog 
where iAssetId = 1 
Order By dtUtcDateTime DESC
```

We don't search based on the PK, BUT we are inserting data into this table every few seconds.

My questions are:

Because we are inserting data every few seconds do I need to create a clustered index on the PK?

**OR**, should I create a clustered index on `iAssetId` and `dtUtcDateTime` like this?

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX
[VehicleMonitoringLog_Asset_dtmUTCDateTime_ClusteredIndex]

ON [dbo].[VehicleMonitoringLog] ( [iAssetId] ASC, [dtUTCDateTime] ASC )
WITH ( PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, 
    DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
    ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**EDIT**: These are the 3 columns in Question:

[image]

I have added an image showing the PK and FK of the Table. Another search we do is something like this:

```
Select * from VehicleMonitoringLogs 
where iAssetId = 1 
and dtUTCDateTime > GetDate() - 1 
and dtUTCDateTime  <  GetDate() 
Order by dtUTCDateTime ASC
```

Comment: Since you are ordering on `dtUTCDateTime`, and you are probably doing range searches on it, it would make sense to create a clustered index on that column and a non clustered index on `iAssetId`. But there are many possible answers. You need to 1. Measure insert and select performance and capture the query plan, 2. Apply Indexes 3. Measure insert and select performance and capture the query plan. 4. Repeat from 2, but with a different set of indexes. Then you can make a decision on what is the best index. Heaps aren't always bad as long as you have a reason for implementing it that way.

Answer (score 2):

The clustered index in your question will optimize the select query because:

1) you are requesting all columns

2) the first column satisfies the equality predicate on iAssetID

3) the second column is useful for the dtUTCDateTime inequality predicate

Since you also have a surrogate iVehicleMonitoringId key that serves no purpose other than to provide a unique value, consider changing your primary key to a clustered composite one on iAssetId, dtUTCDateTime, and iVehicleMonitoringId.  That would avoid the need for a separate index.  My assumption is you have no tables that reference this log table so the wider key shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Will this index slow down the insert, because we are inserting records every few seconds, or in some cases every second, then SQL Server will have to insert in the correct order (i.e. iAssetId), The dtUTCDateTime inserted will always be the latest time.

Comment: @DawoodAwan, compared to an additional index, I suspect insert performance will be better with the single index but you'll need to test to verify.  A few rows per second isn't much to be worried about, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Heap's are better for inserting into because they don't suffer the performance (albeit small) of working out where in the B-Tree to put your row and then adjust if necessary the index nodes in the tree.

If that is the only query you are running then a non-clustered index as follows would be best:

```
create nonclustered index nc_blah on VehicleMonitoringLog ( iAssetId, dtUTCDateTime desc )
```

The data will be indexed in the correct order for your query.

I wouldn't use a clustered index with the above because you'd be constantly suffering from page splits on the whole table rather than just the non-clustered index.

I've assumed your PK is ( iAssetId, dtUTCDateTime )

Comment: I have edit the question which shows the PK, and also another Query in which we search by dtUTCDateTime  Ascending. So you are saying I don't really need a clustered index on this table?

Comment: The primary purpose of an index is to improve read (and sometimes write) performance. Do you have a read performance issue? If so, one option is to create index(es). The _order_ of the columns in the index is important. I suggest the first column should be `dUTCDateTime`, not `iAssetId`.